# Como alinhar uma div com display inline-block?

Tags: css, front-end

Tenho um feed de notícias que consiste em duas **divs** *inline-block*.

**1°** - A primeira contem o título e imagem da notícia (**esquerda**).
**2°** - A outra o conteúdo da notícia (**direita**).

Queria que mesmo que os parágrafos do conteúdo da notícia variem de notícia para notícia, que alinha-se ao centro da **div** da esquerda.

Algo assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso conseguir este resultado ?(desculpem pelas mad photoshop skillz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

você pode colocá-las alinhadas lado a lado usando float. Daí a largura será respeitada, e não importa quanto texto você colocar na div da direita.

Segue um exemplo de código:

```
    <div class="div-esquerda">
       img and titulo
    </div>

    <div class="div-direita">
       linhas e linhas de conteudo
    </div>

    <style type="text/css">
       .div-esquerda {
          width: 40%;
          float: left;
       }

       .div-direita {
              text-align: center;
              float: right;
              width: 55%;
       }
```

Comment: Assim tão simples :) obg!